# insert single data in data base but in data base duplicate row also added at time of insertion

Tags: java, jdbc

I would like to insert single data in data base at a time but in data base duplicate row generate at a time.

```
-----------------------------
Output(in mysql table=privilege)
----------------------------- 
id privilege
1  abc
2  abc
```

Here's how I insert the data:

```
public int addPrivilege(String privilege) {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    String sqlprivilege;
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    int pinsert = 0;
    try {
        sqlprivilege = "insert into privilege(privilege) values(?)";
        dbConnection = ConnectionDao.getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlprivilege);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, privilege);
        pinsert = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        if(preparedStatement.executeUpdate()==1)
            pinsert=1;
        else
            pinsert=0;
        System.out.println("privilege is add and name is:- " +privilege);
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            try {
                dbConnection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    return pinsert;
}
```

Comment: Yep, you're doing `preparedStatement.executeUpdate()` twice.

Answer (score 2):

You execute the sql twice in your code.

```
1) pinsert = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
2) if(preparedStatement.executeUpdate()==1)
```

I'm not sure about the return values of the executeUpdate. But i think the first is enough, no need to check for the return values. If you need to then compare with pinsert instead of executeupdate (again).

```
if(pinsert == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two time executeUpdate(); delete execute which one is in if case

```
    public int addPrivilege(String privilege) {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    String sqlprivilege;
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    int pinsert = 0;
    try {
        sqlprivilege = "insert into privilege(privilege) values(?)";
        dbConnection = ConnectionDao.getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlprivilege);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, privilege);
        pinsert = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        //try this
        if(pinsert ==1)
            pinsert=1;
        else
            pinsert=0;
        System.out.println("privilege is add and name is:- " +privilege);
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            try {
                dbConnection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    return pinsert;
}
```

Comment: Seems unnecessary to set pinsert to 1 if it's 1.